# How to check css class of a row in jquery datatable using rows.every() method

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to check if the rows of a datatable have a particular class.

```
var tab = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "rowCallback":function(row,data,index){
      $(row).addClass('testCVs');
     }
});

tab.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop){
     console.log($(this).hasClass('testCVs'));
}
```

The log returns false value.
How do I check the presence of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$(this.node()).hasClass('testCVs');`. `this` does not refer to the actual row element. See the datatables documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().node().